# Array Pointers and Manipulation

Tags: c

Suppose I have:

```
int (* arrPtr)[10] = NULL; // A pointer to an array of ten elements with type int.
int (*ptr)[3]= NULL;
int var[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int matrix[3][10];
```

Now if I do,

```
arrPtr = matrix;     //.....This is fine...
```

Now can I do this:

```
ptr =  var;          //.....***This is working***
```

OR is it compulsory to do this:

```
ptr= (int (*)[10])var;         //....I dont understand why this is necessary
```

Also,

```
printf("%d",(*ptr)[4]);
```

is working even though we declare

```
int (*ptr)[3]=NULL;
          ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, Name of Array is Pointer to it's First Location.
So, when you do,

```
ptr = var;
```

You are assigning address of `var[0]` to `ptr[0]` 
`int var[10]` declaration makes `var` as an int pointer
As both are int pointers, the operation is valid.

For Second Question,
When you declare a Pointer, It points to some address.
Say

```
int * ptr = 0x1234; //Some Random address
```

now when you write ptr[3], it's `0x1234 + (sizeof(int) * 3)`.
So Pointer works irrespective of it's declared array size.

So when ptr = NULL,
*ptr[4] will point to `NULL + (sizeof(int) * 4)`
i.e. A Valid Operation!

Comment: No, the name of an array is *not* just a pointer to its first element.  It's *the name of the array*, an expression of array type.  This expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element in most, but not all, contexts.  For example, given `int var[10];`, `sizeof var` yields the size of the array object, *not* the size of a pointer.  Similarly, `&var` gives you the address of the entire array object (of type `int (*)[10]`), not the address of the first element (of type `int*`).  See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Ohh... Thanks for Pointing it out and clearing my concept!! But in this case `var` can be used as pointer to first location of Array, Right? I'll edit my post... Thanks!

Comment: Yes -- but I'd say that `var` *is converted to* a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: I am still not clear with this:..... ptr = var; //.....***This is working*** OR is it compulsory to do this: ptr= (int (*)[10])var; //....I dont understand why this is necessary

Comment: @Mayuresh: This is not at all compulsory to do so... But it will be a good practise if you do so... Will result into More Precise coding... That's all!

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` and `var` aren't compatible pointers because `ptr` is a pointer to an array of 3 ints and `var` is an array of 10 ints, 3 ≠ 10.

`(*ptr)[4]` works likely because the compiler doesn't do rigorous boundary checks when indexing arrays. This probably has to do with the fact that a lot of existing C code uses variable-size structures defined something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int type;
  size_t size; // actual number of chars in data[]
  unsigned char data[1];
} DATA_PACKET;
```

The code allocates more memory to a `DATA_PACKET*` pointer than `sizeof(DATA_PACKET)`, here it would be `sizeof(DATA_PACKET)-1+how many chars need to be in data[]`.

So, the compiler ignores index=4 when dereferencing `(*ptr)[4]` even though it's >= 3 in the declaration `int (*ptr)[3]`.

Also, the compiler cannot always keep track of arrays and their sizes when accessing them through pointers. Code analysis is hard.

Comment: I am still not clear with this:.....                             ptr =  var;          //.....***This is working***

OR is it compulsory to do this:

ptr= (int (*)[10])var; //....I dont understand why this is necessary

Comment: @Mayuresh: technically, `ptr=var;` must always work. At least, I can't see a good reason why it can't. But still, the pointer types in this case are different and if there's no type cast, the compiler can treat this assignment as erroneous and refuse to compile or issue a warning. Without the cast gcc issues `warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type`, Turbo C++ issues `Warning: Suspicious pointer conversion` while Open Watcom C doesn't care about the missing cast at all.

Answer (score 0):

ptr is a pointer to array of 3 integers, so ptr[0] will point to the start of the first array, ptr[1] will point to the start of the second array and so on.

In your case:

> printf("%d",(*ptr)[4]);

works as you print the element no 5 of the first array

and

> printf("%d",(*ptr+1)[4]);

print the element no 5 of the second array ( which of course doesn't exists)

for example the following is the same as yours

> printf("%d",ptr[0][4]);

but this doesn't mean that you depend on this as var is array of 10 integers, so ptr has to be decelared as

> int *ptr = NULL

in this case to print the element no 5

> printf("%d", ptr[4]);